# SQL having clause of a partitioned column

Tags: sql-server, nested, sql-order-by, partition, having-clause

When I make this query unnested (including the --'s) I get what I am looking for. However, I only want row number (rn) <=10. Then when I nest it I receive an error concerning my ORDER BY and HAVING.

```
--SELECT *
--FROM(
    SELECT InvoiceNo, DescriptionofService, SUM(Price) AS Total_Price,year(invoicedate) AS 'Year', COUNT(DescriptionofService) AS cnt
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceNo ORDER BY COUNT(DescriptionofService) DESC, SUM(Price) DESC) AS rn
        FROM Billing_Lab_Invoice
            WHERE year(Invoicedate) = 2020 
            GROUP BY InvoiceNo, DescriptionofService, year(invoicedate)
            ORDER BY InvoiceNo, cnt DESC, Total_Price DESC
--          ) 
--  HAVING rn <= 10
```

Here's my readout before I try to filter the row number column

```
64941452    A   87.50   2020    25  1
64941452    B   62.50   2020    25  2
64941452    C   81.00   2020    18  3
64941452    D   44.00   2020    11  4
......
64941452    E   22.50   2020    3   14
```

*EDIT*
This worked, but not sure why

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
;WITH CTE AS (  
    SELECT InvoiceNo
        , DescriptionofService
        , SUM(Price) AS Total_Price
        ,year(invoicedate) AS 'Year'
        , COUNT(DescriptionofService) AS cnt
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (
            PARTITION BY InvoiceNo ORDER BY COUNT(DescriptionofService) DESC, SUM(Price) DESC) AS rn 
        FROM Billing_Lab_Invoice
            WHERE year(Invoicedate) = 2020 
            GROUP BY InvoiceNo, DescriptionofService, year(invoicedate)
            )
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE [rn] <=10
```

64941452    A 87.50 2020    25  1
64941452    B 62.50 2020    25  2
64941452    C 81.00 2020    18  3
64941452    D 44.00 2020    11  4
64941452    D 50.00 2020    10  5
64941452    E 161.00 2020   7   6
64941452    F 22.50 2020    6   7
64941452    G 504.352020    5   8
64941452    H 40.00 2020    5   9
64941452    I 40.00 2020    5   10
64946394    A 351.00    2020    78  1
64946394    B 199.50    2020    57  2

Comment: Replace your `HAVING` with `WHERE` in your outer select.

Comment: I still recieve this msg.  The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Change this "SELECT InvoiceNo, ..." to "SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT InvoiceNo, .."

Answer (score 0):

Modify your original `SELECT` like so:

```
SELECT x.* FROM (
    
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
        InvoiceNo, DescriptionofService, SUM(Price) AS Total_Price,year(invoicedate) AS 'Year', COUNT(DescriptionofService) AS cnt
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceNo ORDER BY COUNT(DescriptionofService) DESC, SUM(Price) DESC) AS rn
    FROM Billing_Lab_Invoice
    WHERE year(Invoicedate) = 2020 
    GROUP BY InvoiceNo, DescriptionofService, year(invoicedate)
    ORDER BY InvoiceNo, cnt DESC, Total_Price DESC

) AS x
WHERE x.rn <= 10;
```

Technically you're not supposed top be able to ORDER nested data unless you're specifying `TOP`. Using `TOP 100 PERCENT` gets around that, returning all matching records.